# findBy not working with inherited properties

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following model and repository:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "db_user", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email") })
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_user")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_user", sequenceName = "seq_user")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie extends AbstractItem {
    // Id column inherited from AbstractItem

    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "movie_user")
public class MovieOwnership extends AbstractOwnership {

    @ManyToOne
    private Movie movie;

    // ...
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractOwnership{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_default", sequenceName = "seq_default")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_default")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;

    // ...
}


public interface MovieOwnershipRepository extends QueryDslJpaRepository<MovieOwnership, Long> {

    List<MovieOwnership> findByOwnerId(Long ownerId);

    MovieOwnership findByOwnerIdAndMovie(Long ownerId, Movie movieId);

    List<MovieOwnership> findByOwnerIdAndMovieIdIn(Long ownerId, Set<Long> movieIds);
}
```

I'm trying to use Spring's findBy requests to fetch MovieOwnerships by owner or movie, using the id field of both entities. I'm able to work directly with the owner's id, but using MovieId in my requests seems broken (I can use the whole Movie object though). In the code above, the first two findBy are fine but the last one throws this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate
>   Attribute  with the the given name [movieId] on this ManagedType
>   [carrm.app.data.AbstractOwnership]

It compiles if I try with another property from Movie (like findByMovieTitle), but I can't make it work on the id.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Where is defined the movieId properties?

Comment: Which of the three methods are you calling?

Comment: Does this code even compile? You have an interface extending a class (QuerydslJpaRepository)

Comment: @XavierBouclet the movieId property refers to the id field of MovieOwnership's movie field, just like ownerId refers to the id property of the User.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I called the first two methods with success, but adding the third one brokes the app.

Comment: @AlanHay it doesn't compile because of the last method of the repository, but this code works fine if I remove it and keep the first two methods.

Comment: I'm afraid but you probably found a bug! I will try to reproduce this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same with JpaRepository instead of QueryDslJpaRepository.

The SQL is generated correctly:

```
select movieowner0_.id as id1_1_, movieowner0_.owner_id as owner_id2_1_, movieowner0_.movie_id as movie_id3_1_ 
from movie_ownership movieowner0_ 
left outer join user user1_ on movieowner0_.owner_id=user1_.id 
left outer join movie movie2_ on movieowner0_.movie_id=movie2_.id 
where user1_.id=? and (movie2_.id in (?))
```

So it must be a QueryDslJpaRepository implementation bug.

I would suggest you use JpaRepository instead.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong exactly with my custom repository since it works well with User's attributes, but changing it to JpaRepository worked.

Comment: QueryDslJpaRepository is deprecated and should no longer be used https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/QuerydslJpaRepository.html